# Cannot connect to a local web service from my android emulator

Tags: java, android, networking

I am having a problem connecting from the emulator to a local web server. I can connect to it outside the emulator.
Emulator gets:
`org.apache.http.conn.httphostconnectexception connection to http //localhost;808 refused`

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products,
                    "GET", params);
            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());
            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Got an IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting to `http://10.0.2.2:8080` instead.

The `10.0.2.2` IP address is special within the emulator and will transparently connect to your host development machine's localhost (`127.0.0.1`).

If you use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` within the emulator, this will refer to the internal emulated loopback interface instead. This is useful if you have another program running in the emulator, acting as a TCP or UDP server at the same port. However, in your specific case, you really want to get 'out of the sandbox'.

The [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking) has more information (and examples).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong network address to access the web service.

`http://localhost` goes to the device in an Android emulator. Use `10.0.2.2` to access your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine).

See [Android Emulator Networking](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking)

**EDIT:** Your exception says `http //localhost;808`, but your hostname should be `http //localhost:808` with a `:` instead of `;`.